# Add iframe to page on prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Prestashop doesn't save iframe

I have enabled in the settings Allow iframes in HTML fields to YES. I tried to add an iframe through a custom tpl, but if there is an iframe in the custom tpl, then the page gives a 500 error. I have prestashop 1.7.8.8

Comment: Update your post with codes please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Allow iframes in HTML fields to YES

This is related to the form fields which allows HTML, on a TPL you should be use whatever you need without being affected by that setting.

> but if there is an iframe in the custom tpl, then the page gives a 500
> error

A 500 error can be also a masked error on the PHP / TPL. So maybe you have some issues on the TPL which are unrelated to the iframe.

My recommendation would be to enable the debug mode on the configuration file located at /config/defines.inc.php

```
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
}
```

Then check the template again and see if there is an error on the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we solved the problem in a different way: commented out the code that checks for the presence of an iframe